# How can I prove that I am familiar with a certain technology?

Tags: job-search, software-development, learning

During a job interview I was asked if I had any experience with *Software Technology X*.

I had not.

But I was curious and afterwards I got intensively involved with *Software Technology X*.
I watched countless videos on Youtube and have now even completed an online course on this topic.
Additionally I started to develop open source projects with *Software Technology X*.
Unfortunately this technology is not used in my current company.

How can I make future employers assume that I am proficient in *Software Technology X* even though I am just doing it as a hobby?

Comment: Have a certificate or a proof in form of tool created in STX that tick all the boxes for mastery of STX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mention the specific open source projects you've developed using STX. In addition to being more convincing than just putting it in a long list of "technologies used", that lets the person reviewing your resume actually look at your use of STX.

When reviewing a resume, I love love *love* seeing open source projects listed, and I trust them over work history "responsibilities" as indicators of skills. "Developed high-performance SQL queries" in your work experience might mean that you're an experienced SQL wizard, or it might just mean that you added a column to someone else's table. But if you've got a GitHub link, there's no ambiguity about your contributions.

And then don't worry too much. "Just doing it as a hobby" may have been a big problem once, but it's at most a minor consideration now. Everybody's come to understand that in software development, people can build expertise even when they're not being paid for it.

Comment: The only thing I would add that OP should really avoid using the word "mastered". Be realistic and manage expectations, and if you will come to an interview as master of STX, you may very well be grilled at that level. And unless OP has level of understanding that he knows the internals of STX, and possibly could contribute to how it's built, the master claim is slightly overblown.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul That's a good point. Particularly if they're showing code, "mastered" is an invitation to disappointment.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I guess "mastered" came from the automatic translation since I am not a native english speaker. "Familiar" would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can, put together some sample work or code done using it and send it in along with your job application in the future. This is what I did for my current job, even though I used the technology at work at a previous job. I couldn't give them work from that job, so did a bit in my spare time at home and used samples from that.

Answer (score 1):

Be honest, State that you fit their profile for a backend/frontend/fullstack developer and that you have experience from Y technology and that you also have experience with x technology which you´ve learned on you own.

You might add on your CV a "statbar" of the technologies you know and fill it in honestly how well you know it. You might say that you are a master on technology y but pretty good on technology x. That way they get some scope

I think they care less about you are a maste of technology X then that they know that you know how to code. They can always help fill in the blanks. I once sent in a website I had buildt with PHP for a ASP job and I got hired. Ofc I knew asp but that was less important. All they wanted to know was that I wasn´t a fraudster who claimed to know how to code despite not actually knowing anything. Which happens ever so often in the technology world.

I also recommend that you add that final touch to your cv and use a free template service like www.canva.com. You need to show to them that you really want to work there. Remember you are selling yourself. They are the buyer. So package yourself as an honset, hard working person who focus on every detail. I also recommend practicing coding interviews on youtube.